# Normalize each individual frequency after FFT

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am writing a program that is supposed to visually display the frequencies that make up audio.  To do this I have a rolling window that I perform an FFT on (I'll post code at bottom).  What interested me is that all my plots have a high power near the 0hz side and a low power near the 10khz side:
[image]
[image]

I want to change the graph so that instead of showing the actual power it shows the power relative to the power at the same frequency to the rest of the song.  For example, I want to have it so that the maximum value at the 0hz is the same as the maximum value at the 10khz.  This would mean reducing the y value at low frequencies and raising it at high frequencies.  How would I go about doing this and make it look like the graph isn't on a downward slope?

As a side note after I get the algorithm working I am going to stream the audio rather than reading it from a audio file so that may eliminate the possibility of keeping an average of each frequency throughout the entire song.

```
% Prototype to graph moving window of FFT through an audio file in real time
clear all;
warning('off','MATLAB:colon:nonIntegerIndex'); % Suppress integer operand errors because it's ok to round for the window size

% Read Audio
fs = 44100;         % sample frequency (Hz)
full = audioread('O.mp3');

% Remove leading 0's and select range
for i = 1:fs
    if full(i) ~= 0
        crop = i;
        break
    end
end
full = full(crop:end);

startTime = 0;
endTime = length(full)/fs;

% Play song
tic
player = audioplayer(full(fs*startTime+1:fs*endTime), fs);
player.play();
initialTime = toc;

% Perform fft and get frequencies (hopefully in realish time with audio)
windowSize = fs/8;
for i = windowSize/2+1+fs*startTime : fs/16 : fs*endTime
    beginningChunk = round(i-windowSize/2);
    endChunk = round(i+windowSize/2);

    x = full(beginningChunk:endChunk);
    y = fft(x);
    n = length(x);          % number of samples in chunk
    power = abs(y).^2/n;    % power of the DFT
    power = power(1:end/2);
    f = (0:n-1)*(fs/n);     % frequency range
    f = f(1:end/2);
    while initialTime+i/fs > toc
        pause(.0001);
    end
    figure(1);
    plot(f,power);
    axis([0 10000 0 5]);
    xlabel('Frequency');
    ylabel('Power');
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using an [Emphasis filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(telecommunications)) to elevate/emphasize signal power in the higher frequencies?

Comment: The emphasis filter is a good idea.  How would I go about figuring out how much to emphasize at each frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Represent power as a z-score

**Prepare `[t,f]` samples for baseline**

```
winrange = windowSize/2+1+fs*startTime : fs/16 : fs*endTime;
for i = winrange
   ...
   % base_pow is [# of time bins,# freq bins] 
   base_pow(i == winrange,:) = power(1:end/2);
   ...
end
```

**Normalize each sample by baseline data**

```
for i = winrange
   ...
   raw_pow = power(1:end/2);
   % collapse across 1st dimension of base_pow
   norm_pow = (raw_pow - mean(base_pow,1))./std(base_pow,[],1)
   ...
end
```

**Signal streaming**

The above solution requires you to use the full sample. A more computationally efficient method would be to fit some function to several audio tracks before streaming any sample and use that curve for normalization.

Comment: Re: Signal streaming: or you could adjust your baseline data as you stream.

Comment: Ok that's helpful.  Considering audio is a big topic do you think I could find a rule or research paper or something of someone that has already found a curve to fit most audio well?

Comment: No. There's an interesting topic, [colors of noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise) (where we get _white noise_), that describes how the shape of the power spectrum explains the audible noise in a sample. There is not a universal spectral shape when it comes to audio.

Comment: I'm confused about how the article connects to my problem.  When I think of noise I think of unwanted sounds.  I get the impression this article is talking about the power spectrum of unwanted sounds.  I'm not dealing with "noise"(in the sense of unwanted information in a signal).  I'm trying to fit the power spectrum of specifically music tracks to a power spectrum that would on average have equal adjusted power across any bandwidth (coincidentally how the white noise graph looks).

Comment: If you played the frequency-transformed average of all tracks it would sound like noise. The shape of that noise will most likely be determined by recording/sampling practices and commonly used sounds/instruments. I introduced colors of noise to show that you are not going to find a universal _audio_ power spectral curve to describe the average shape of generic samples.